# How to test whether a variable is equal to one of five Array Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I am storing five values in an array and I need to check whether a variable I've set up is equal to one of those values. Here is what I mean:

```
var x = e.clientX, // horizontal mouse position
myArray = []; // I have another function that stores five values in this array

if(x == /*one of the five array values*/){
    //do something
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Loop over the array.

Comment: Do you need to know the specific position?

Comment: @Andrew L You mean the value position, like `myArray[0]`, `myArray[1]`,`myArray[2]`? In that case, no. All I need is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which checks if the array includes the value. Note that this **is not supported on Internet Explorer**, you can find the polyfill at the mentioned link. Per the documentation:

> `Array.prototype.includes`
>
> The **`includes()`** method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
if(myArray.includes(x)) {
    //x is in myArray
}
```

If you want the position, you may use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
myArray.indexOf(x);
```

This will search for item and return the position. If not found, it will return -1. This can be applied to work with IE:

```
if(myArray.indexOf(x) > -1) {
    //x is in myArray
}
```

This makes sure it exists because it checks if the position is greater than -1.

Comment: No support in IE.

Comment: Thanks or your help! In my code, I want to define a _range_ of values, like so: `if(x - 50 >= someVar && x+50 <= someVar)`. Supposing that `someVar` is a value in `myArray`, is this: `if(myArray.indexOf(x - 50) > -1 && myArray.indexOf(x + 50) > -1 )` the same as the former statement?

Comment: @eow2898 What do you mean a range of values? A range in the array?

Comment: @AndrewL. It's a set of values that are greater than, equal to, and less than x. I know that `if(x - 50 >= someVar && x+50 <= someVar)` works. So how can I recreate that statement using `myArray.indexOf(x)`?

Comment: @eow2898 `indexOf` returns the index of the element in the array. Adding 50 is probably not what you want. I'm a bit busy right now, I can try to get back later

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` and check if the return value is greater than or equal to zero.  `indexOf` returns the index of an object in an array, or -1 if it is not present.  You could also use `includes`, but it's not fully supported in all browsers yet.  `includes` returns `true` if the value is present in the array.

```
var x = e.clientX, // horizontal mouse position
myArray = []; // I have another function that stores five values in this array
if(myArray.indexOf(x)>=0) { // one of the five array values
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myArray.indexOf(x) > -1)
{
 // value exists - do something
}
```

myArray.indexOf(x) will return -1 if the value doesn't exist in the array.
It will return the value's index if it exists in the array.

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: W3Schools isn't the most reliable documentation

Comment: @AndrewL. Would [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) be considered reliable?

Comment: @AndrewL. I did not defend W3Schools. Instead I pointed to an alternate reference and asked if it was reliable - or at least less objectionable.

Comment: @DFriend I'd say it's a more *complete* documentation and is more up to date. W3Schools seems like more of a tutorial-based site.

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if something is in an Array, and it's backward compatible.

```
function inArray(val, ary){
  for(var i=0,l=ary.length; i<l; i++){
    if(ary[i] === val){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
/*
// use inArray
if(inArray(yourValHere, yourArrayHere)){
  // it's in yourArrayHere so do stuff here
}
// use not inArray
if(!inArray(yourValHere, yourArrayHere)){
  // it's not in yourArrayHere so do stuff here
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in ES6

```
var value = 5,
  myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
myArray.some(item => item === value); // <-- true
```